# Is it better to use shell commands inside a C programm or to write a shell script that will use some form of C code?

Tags: c, shell

I am currently working on a little project which aims to automate a specific task.
But to do so, I need both Shell commands (Linux) and another language (C) in order to treat the output of my shell commands. But my goal is to make it fully automated so that when I run the script/program, I only give it my arguments and everything is done for me.

So I was wondering which is the best option between :

1. Writing a little Shell script that will first run the shell commands I need and redirect the output of these commands into a .txt file and then execute my C program that will do the treatment of the output as I want it to

OR

2. Write only one C program that will do everything, using the system() and popen() functions but I don't feel very familiar with this way of doing things because I never used these functions before and it seems a little bit messy

And of course if you have any suggestions other than the two I mentioned, please tell me ! I am doing this project partly to learn how to use Shell scripting and C ,because I did something similar but a lot less "complex" (if we can call such a simple project complex) with python but I wasn't satisfied and I much prefer C over python for coding tools that I will use in the future.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There are no generic answers. This strongly depends on the "specific task" you want to automate, and also on other topics, like portability, time constraints, speed requirement . So what task exactly do you want to automate and in what way?

Comment: You don't need to go through a temporary .txt file. Write your C program to process stdin and write to stdout, and you can *pipe* your data through it. Perhaps make it generally useful and re-usable. Perhaps future shell users will use your program just like they use sed, awk or less today. ;-) Personally, I dislike `system()` et al.

Comment: Yes i think I'll try to pipe it directly into my C program but I never did that before so I'll just have to read a bit about it before I create a complete disaster.

Comment: @lucasdctr: There is no magic to it. A shell's pipe (like `grep foo bar.txt | less`) just forwards the `stdout` of the former program to the `stdin` to the latter. `stdin` and `stdout` are `FILE *` just like a "normal" opened stream as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. Why not use the shell script to call your program at the end?

It will run all the stuff it should and in the end, instead of redirecting the result to a txt, it directly redirects the result into your C program stdin, which should be as simple as:

```
shell script result | ./main
```